# Autodesk Forge does not allow multiple OAuth2 callback URL for one app

Tags: autodesk-forge

It is common to have multiple environments doing dev, staging and production. Forge App creation page also instruction that this is possible. However, no matter how I fill in the field, I always get a rejection. Please instruct how this field can be filled in with more than one callback URL. [image]

Comment: Duplicate of [How to specify multiple callback urls](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69014486/how-to-specify-multiple-callback-urls-for-autodesk-forge-app)

Answer (score -1):

Currently it is only possible to specify a single callback URL. You *can* however change it whenever needed, by clicking the EDIT button in your Forge application page.

Btw. we are already working on adding support to multiple callback URLs but don't have an ETA on when it's going to be available to the public.

Comment: 1. Changing it to point to localhost is not possible for production deployment.
2. Requiring a single callback URL forces us to create new, separate apps for dev environments, which forces us to re-upload bundles, re-create activities, which becomes quite manual and repetitive.

Comment: Which also requires us to re-add it to the BIM360 accounts.

Comment: I agree this is not ideal. At the same time, it _is_ recommended to use separate Forge apps for your production/staging/dev environments. Btw. I believe you should be able to share your DA app bundles and activities with other Forge apps: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66746151/how-to-create-public-forge-design-automation-activity-and-package